# WebRTC Non-Guaranteed Data Sending Model Needing a Piece of Guaranteed Data

Tags: websocket

For games it is best to have non-guaranteed sent data, otherwise the game slows down while it waits.

However, when one user initiates a game, then that has to be guaranteed data, otherwise the other guy does not have the game info, such at length of a timed game, the dungeon map being used, etc.

So how do you overcome the idea that the game-start-info has to be guaranteed, while in-game movement of the player characters does not have to be guaranteed during the game?

Also, in general, how do you start a timed multi-player game?